# Creating a box with different colored sides using BufferGeometry in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Using Three.js, I would like to create a box that you are able to change the color of on all sides using BufferGeometry. My current solution is creating boxes like this:

```js
// Creating the Cube
let cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1), [new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xffffff,
  vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors
}), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xffffff,
  vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
  transparent: true,
  opacity: 0
})]);

// Editing the sides (have to set +1 because CubeGeometry has 12 sides with 2 triangles per side)
cube.geometry.faces[faceIndex].color.set(new THREE.Color(color));
cube.geometry.faces[faceIndex + 1].color.set(new THREE.Color(color));
```

The problems with this being that CubeGeometry is deprecated and this solution has very bad performance wise because BufferGeometry is not being utilized. I've tried to use BoxBufferGeometry but it does not allow you to edit individual faces in the same way. I also don't know if the Three.js built in ray tracer will be able to pick out sides of a BoxBufferGeometry mesh like it does for CubeGeometry.

Comment: You could go for the easy route and initialize the mesh with BoxGeometry, change to face colors like you would normally, then afterwards set cube.geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().from( cubeGeometry ); OR initialize it with boxBufferGeometry, use the index array of the geometry to find the face indices, set the colors in a new BufferAttribute and add that to the geometry.Maybe this example helps: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_indexed. The raycaster WILL return the face on bufferGeometries!

Comment: or even better; let geometry = new BoxGeometry(); Then set you face colors. Then let cube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(geometry), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xffffff,
  vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
  transparent: true,
  opacity: 0
}));

Comment: @EthanHermsey With this solution, are you able to change the colors of each side after the initial creation?

Comment: Yes, because you change the face colors the same way as before. I've made a small example here: https://jsfiddle.net/EthanHermsey/rgk6oc3v/7/

Comment: o wait.. AFTER initial creating.. You can do that with buffer geometries; through the mesh.geometry.attributes.colors array. Is it really that important to have buffergeometries? You could just leave them as boxGeometries......

Comment: @EthanHermsey Thanks for your responses. Currently I’m using boxgeometries but suffering performance issues due to there being a lot of them and because of raytracing.